# Why I get an XmlException "Unexpected end of file" with the TextMessageEncodingBindingElement?

Tags: .net, wcf

I try to do something really simple in theory : deserialize a string to a Message, here is the code :

```
[TestMethod]
public void EncoderErrorTest()
{
    var message = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://tempuri.org/IHelloWorldService/SayHello</a:Action></s:Header><s:Body><SayHello xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><name>Nico</name></SayHello></s:Body></s:Envelope>";

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(message);
    stream.Position = 0;
    var soapMessage = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement().CreateMessageEncoderFactory().Encoder.ReadMessage(stream, 99999);
    Assert.IsNotNull(soapMessage);
}
```

But during the deserialization I get a XmlException "Unexpected end of file".
Is something wrong with my code ?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try calling `Flush` on your `StreamWriter` before you read from the stream (or better yet, put it in a `using`-block).

Comment: `MemoryStream` isn't caching, as far as I know (would be pretty pointless - why do a memory cache for a memory-backed stream?), but it wouldn't hurt anyway.

Comment: The fewer exceptions to the "use using blocks" rule, the better.